# How to include a module dependency as a part of py2exe script

Tags: python

I got a windows installer my_script.exe (generated out of my_script.py using py2exe) which is dependent on "PyDes" module,

when I execute my_script.exe it throws an error saying ,

Import error : pyDes module

How to include the pyDes module as a dependency to my_script.py

I am using py2exe to create windows installer.

python setup.py py2exe

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `'includes': ['PyDes'],` to the relevant spot in your `setup.py` file

```
setup(
    # ...
    options = {
        'includes': ['PyDes'],
        },
    # ...
)
```

assuming that `PyDes` is in your `sys.path`

N.B. If `py2exe` hasn't picked up the `PyDes` dependency, chances are it hasn't picked up anything that `PyDes` depends on so be prepared for more `ImportError`'s! Just keep adding them to the `'include'` until it all works out.

Comment: Not working. Still gives out error saying dependency missing.